# Java Parsing Issue- How to Receive data from Server?

Tags: java

I have a client code which is sending the Request `Push 567` and I am manipulating the number in the server and sending back to client. My code is working for sample integer number but I have problem when I include String with number say PUSH 567. It works fine when I just put number 567 and take off integer value of in the server program.

EDIT:Its working for just string or just integers but not when I parse it.

Client code

```
 public class Client 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",1342);
Scanner sc1=new Scanner(s.getInputStream()); 
  String req = "PUSH 567";

  PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
  p.println(req);

  int temp=sc1.nextInt();
  System.out.println(temp);

}
}
```

Server Code

```
  public class NewServer 
  {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    ServerSocket k=new ServerSocket(1342);
    Socket ss=k.accept();
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());

    String s  = sc.next();
    int i = Integer.valueOf(s);
    int temp=i+2;

    PrintStream p=new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
    p.println(temp);

}
}
```

Error I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Tester.Client.main(Client.java:24)
```

Comment: You're sending 'PUSH 567' but your server is coded as though there was only a number in the input. Your server must therefore be failing with a `NumberFormatException`, which will cause it to exit rather than send anything back, which will cause the client failure.

Comment: try printing the string itself and see what you get

Comment: @EJP I thought parsing was enough. What changes do I have to make ?

Comment: Its working for just string or just integers.

Comment: @JavaHopper It works for String

Comment: Try sc.nextInt() in place of sc.next(), and change String s to int. This will scan the next int from the input.

Comment: @Fred same No such Element exception.

Comment: Parsing *is* enough, if you implement it correctly. You didn't. You are attemping to parse 'PUSH 567' as an integer. It isn't. It will fail. It will throw `NumberFormatException` and most probably exit the JVM. You didn't mention any of that behaviour in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class NewServer {

      public static final void main(final String[] args) {
        int portNumber = 1342;

        try ( 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
          String s = "SERVER: Started.";
          out.println(s);
          while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("RECV: "+s);
              String[] ss = s.split("PUSH\\s");
              out.println(Integer.parseInt(ss[1]) + 2 + "");
              System.out.println("SEND: " + Integer.parseInt(ss[1]) + 2);
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

  public static final void main(final String[] args) {
    String hostName = "127.0.0.1";
    int portNumber = 1342;

    try (
        Socket client = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    ) {
      String fromServer = null;
      client.setKeepAlive(true);
      while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(fromServer);
        out.println("PUSH 567");
      }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```